# I would like to capture image of front, side from 3d obj file

Tags: python, 3d, capture

I have downloaded `.obj` files from link below.

https://graphics.soe.ucsc.edu/data/BodyModels/index.html

Files are 3d scan of human body.

What I want to do is capture the front and side of 3d `.obj` file and save it as `.png` file using python like below image.

Poses of 3d object doesn't have to change like the example.

[image]

Also hope I can see the xticks and yticks so that I can check the length of it.

Can someone please help me? Thank you for reading and have a good day. :)